# Can I make an IOS app that can prevent some IOS features?

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS development.

I was just wondering if it is possible to make an app that will prevent other apps from being opened or an app that will prevent you from going to safari/settings/etc...

Is Apple (IOS) okay with this? I know Android can be different and allows some of these features to persist.

Comment: No and no, I doubt it

Comment: Please have a look at [help/on-topic] since your question will likely be close as too broad. What you're asking for on the other hand is not possible. No apps can modify settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish this in IOS platform , every app is responsible of it's own constraints , permissions and sandbox

Answer (score 0):

No, it can not be possible. Even if you do it some how, apple will reject that.